# div gets selected, and borders appear when it is clicked

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The logo of my wordpress website is inside a div

below is the link

https://www.jbaat.com/

When I click the logo a huge rectangle box appears. I have tried the outline property, and use-select property but its still there.

Comment: `outline: 2px solid #96588a;` this is being applied on focus, line 618 in `wp-content/themes/storefront/style.css?ver=5.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the relevant sections of you code**, which are shown below for future reference, you need to include the following CSS:

```
.custom-logo-link:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

As currently on focus of the `custom-logo-link` the following css is being applied:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
    a:focus, button:focus, .button.alt:focus, input:focus, textarea:focus, input[type="button"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus {
        outline-color: #7c7235;
} 
a:focus, button:focus, .button.alt:focus, input:focus, textarea:focus, input[type="button"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="tel"]:focus, input[type="url"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus {
    outline-color: #7c7235;
}
a:focus, input:focus, textarea:focus, button:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #96588a;
}
```

As well as the generic `:focus` from chrome.

**Your existing (old) code:**

```css
/**
 * Header
 */
.site-header {
  background-color: #2c2d33;
  padding-top: 1.618em;
  padding-bottom: 1.618em;
  color: #9aa0a7;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; }
  .site-header .site-logo-anchor,
  .site-header .site-logo-link,
  .site-header .custom-logo-link {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0; }
    .site-header .site-logo-anchor img,
    .site-header .site-logo-link img,
    .site-header .custom-logo-link img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 210px; }
  .site-header .widget {
    margin-bottom: 0; }

.home.blog .site-header,
.home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header,
.home.post-type-archive-product .site-header {
  margin-bottom: 4.235801032em; }

.no-wc-breadcrumb .site-header {
  margin-bottom: 4.235801032em; }

.no-wc-breadcrumb.page-template-template-homepage .site-header {
  margin-bottom: 0; }

.header-widget-region {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99; }

.site-branding {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: calc( 100% - 120px); }
  .site-branding .site-title {
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin: 0; }
    .site-branding .site-title a {
      font-weight: 700; }
  .site-branding .site-description {
    font-size: 0.875em;
    display: none; }
  .site-branding .logo {
    margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="site-branding">
   <a href="https://www.jbaat.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home"><img width="616" height="626" src="https://www.jbaat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Logo-Jbaat-in-circle.png" class="custom-logo" alt="Logo Jbaat in circle" srcset="https://www.jbaat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Logo-Jbaat-in-circle.png 616w, https://www.jbaat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Logo-Jbaat-in-circle-295x300.png 295w, https://www.jbaat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Logo-Jbaat-in-circle-416x423.png 416w" sizes="(max-width: 616px) 100vw, 616px"></a>  </div>
```